# Pandas plot DataFrame rolling mean gives weird result

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

If I have a DataFrame built as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in range(10)],  
                   'b': [2*i for i in range(10)]})
```

so that its plot of 'b' against 'a' (obtained via `df.plot('a', 'b')`) is simply a straight line, and I compute the running mean of it as

```
rm_df = df.rolling(window=2).mean()
```

and try to plot again 'b' against 'a', I get the reported figure, where the x axis is giving weird values.

[image: weird values in rolling mean df plotting]

I've checked by looking at the dataframe that all values are good, so what is happening?

Comment: I think it's because of `NaN` in the x-axis. Try this:  `rm_df.fillna(0).plot('a','b')`

Comment: (or) specify the required minimum number of observations for each pair by - `df.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean().plot('a', 'b')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in range(10)],  
                   'b': [2*i for i in range(10)]})

rm_df = df.rolling(window=2).mean().plot(
          kind='line', x='a',y='b', use_index=False)
```

Setting `use_index` to false will allow you to specify the columns to be used as x and y

The result will look like this [image]